# Structuring multiple modules in arithmetic quiz

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, module, structure

I have seen previous examples of how to get to this point but the structuring of the program is causing genuine problems for me. Having spent now 3hrs using a `def main()` and ending in `main()`, and conversely no enclosing module within a module, I am no further forward.

I would be grateful for some advice.

```
import random
import operator
def bquiz():



    def randomCalc():
        ops = {'+':operator.add,
                '-':operator.sub,
                '*':operator.mul,
                '/':operator.truediv}
        num1 = random.randint(0,12)
        num2 = random.randint(1,10)   
        op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
        answer = ops.get(op)(num1,num2)
        print('What is {} {} {}?\n'.format(num1, op, num2))
        return answer
    randomCalc()




    def askQuestion():
        answer = randomCalc()
        guess = float(input())
        return guess == answer
    askQuestion()


    def quiz():
        print('Welcome. This is a 10 question math quiz\n')
        score = 0
        for i in range(10):
            correct = askQuestion()
            if correct:
                    score += 1
                    print('Correct!\n')
            else:
                    print('Incorrect!\n')
            return 'Your score was {}/10'.format(score)
    quiz()

bquiz()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not that far off. You just need to put all your functions in the global scope, and then make `quiz` into the main function, like this:

```
import random, operator

def randomCalc():
    ops = {'+':operator.add,
            '-':operator.sub,
            '*':operator.mul,
            '/':operator.truediv}
    num1 = random.randint(0,12)
    num2 = random.randint(1,10)
    op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
    answer = ops.get(op)(num1,num2)
    print('What is {} {} {}?\n'.format(num1, op, num2))
    return answer

def askQuestion():
    answer = randomCalc()
    guess = float(input())
    return guess == answer

def quiz():
    print('Welcome. This is a 10 question math quiz\n')
    score = 0
    for i in range(10):
        correct = askQuestion()
        if correct:
                score += 1
                print('Correct!\n')
        else:
                print('Incorrect!\n')
    print('Your score was {}/10'.format(score))

# start the quiz
quiz()
```

Note that I also changed the last line of `quiz` so that it prints the score, rather than returns it.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things are throwing you here.

First the difference between a python Module and a Function. A function is a sequence of instructions that takes 0 or more inputs and possible returns 0 or more outputs like this.

```
def IsItGood(x):
   return x=='Good'
```

A module is a collection of functions classes, etc that you can use in other python programs using the import statement. In your example below, bquiz, quiz etc. are *functions* not modules.

Second, when you execute a python function, it runs sequentially, executing each line of code along the way. In your original script you had

```
def randomCalc():
    ops = {'+':operator.add,
            '-':operator.sub,
            '*':operator.mul,
            '/':operator.truediv}
    num1 = random.randint(0,12)
    num2 = random.randint(1,10)   
    op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
    answer = ops.get(op)(num1,num2)
    print('What is {} {} {}?\n'.format(num1, op, num2))
    return answer
randomCalc()
```

When you executed your bquiz function, it went ahead and called randomCalc right after you defined it, whereas you only wanted to execute it inside your ask question functions

Third, you don't need bquiz here. When you execute a python file, it will just run from top to bottom executing each step along the way. so if you remove the bquiz function definition and the call to bquiz at the bottom, it has no effect on the program (but will increase performance.

Fourth, look into the difference between "print" and "return". Print writes a string to the console. It's a way of letting your program talk to the user. Return, on the other hand, defines the return value of your function. so

```
return 'Your score was {}/10'.format(score)
```

Won't print anything to the console.

Fifth, and finally, be careful with indentation. Your return statement inside quiz is *inside* your for loop. That means that after the first question, the function will hit the return statement and exit. A function stops executing after it reaches a return statement.

Here is a working version of your quiz.

```
import random
import operator

#Removed bzquiz, since it didn't do anything
def randomCalc():
    ops = {'+':operator.add,
            '-':operator.sub,
            '*':operator.mul,
            '/':operator.truediv}
    num1 = random.randint(0,12)
    num2 = random.randint(1,10)   
    op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
    answer = ops.get(op)(num1,num2)
    print('What is {} {} {}?\n'.format(num1, op, num2))
    return answer
    #Removed randomCalc() call




def askQuestion():
    answer = randomCalc()
    guess = float(input())
    return guess == answer
#Removed askQuestion() call


def quiz():
    print('Welcome. This is a 10 question math quiz\n')
    score = 0
    for i in range(10):
        correct = askQuestion()
        if correct:
                score += 1
                print('Correct!\n')
        else:
                print('Incorrect!\n')
    print 'Your score was {}/10'.format(score)

quiz()

import random
import operator

    def randomCalc():
        ops = {'+':operator.add,
               '-':operator.sub,
               '*':operator.mul,
               '/':operator.truediv}
        num1 = random.randint(0,12)
        num2 = random.randint(1,10)   
        op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
        answer = ops.get(op)(num1,num2)
        print('What is {} {} {}?\n'.format(num1, op, num2))
        return answer





    def askQuestion():
        answer = randomCalc()
        guess = float(input())
        return guess == answer



    def quiz():
        print('Welcome. This is a 10 question math quiz\n')
        score = 0
        for i in range(10):
            correct = askQuestion()
            if correct:
                    score += 1
                    print('Correct!\n')
            else:
                    print('Incorrect!\n')
        print 'Your score was {}/10'.format(score)
    quiz()
bquiz()
```

Comment: Jon, Nick, all - thank you. Brilliant how you walked me through where I went wrong. I have to develop this out further to store/update/sort and return scores achieved by individuals, in three classes (teaching classes), but will play with this over the weekend and may, if you are lucky, come back to you for some assistance. Not entirely sure if I am following stackoverflow procedures but I am learning, on a number of fronts.